# Is the value of a variable in a closure that is called twice the same in both closures?

Tags: javascript

Say that this function is called twice, completely independently. Hence timeout callbacks are created for two functions `fn()` and both functions have a variable called `called` in their closure.

Will this be the same variable or two completely independent variables? Why?

```
function createFunctionWithTimeout(callback, opt_timeout) {
    var called = false;
    function fn() {
        if (!called) {
            called = true;
            callback();
        }
    }
    setTimeout(fn, opt_timeout || 5000);
    return fn;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function closes over a variable declared with `var`. `called` in your scenario will be two completely independent variables because when the function `createFunctionWithTimeout` is called twice, each call "creates" a new variable.

If you call the returned function (`fn`) it will have access to the `called` variable because it also closes over it (nested functions). In this case, `called` is not independent. It belongs to the closure created by the call to `createFunctionWithTimetout`

Answer (score 0):

All declared inside createFunctionWithTimeout will be created on each call.

This called function scope and made like this by design.

Read this article and also look about scope in JS.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

BTW. To make variable `called` be same for each call you need to make it global. Like put it outside of function. In that case they will use same variable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call a new function, it creates its own independent scope and the object inside this scope is only relevant to this particular scope, in otherword, your called variable is two completely independent variables.